# android layout slider in custom listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, slider, custom-lists

[image]

I have this row item in my custom list view, and in my array-adapter which I'm using to populate data in this list contains another list in each item. Which I want to show inside the layout out with arrows (shown in image above).
Any tutorial would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a create your own View for each item in your listview.

This view would probably be a LinearLayout that you could programatically add new views to. Simply loop through your list within each item, generate the textview / image / whatever that you need, and add it to the linearlayout.

Note: your inner list can't be scrollable independently of the main listview.

Comment: After a lot of Google search I realize what I need is a Custom horizontal view inside my list view. I hope this will make you better understand my need.